# Proving that $\mathbb Q(\alpha)=\mathbb Q(\beta)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x):=x^2-3$ over $\mathbb Q$ and let $\beta$ be a root of $g(x):=x^2+6x+6$ over $\mathbb Q$ prove that $\mathbb Q(\alpha)=\mathbb Q(\beta)$

*Attempt:*

The roots of $x^2-3$ are $\pm \sqrt 3$

The roots of $x^2+6x+6$ are $\pm \sqrt 3-3$

$\mathbb Q(\pm \sqrt 3)=\mathbb Q(\pm \sqrt 3-3)$

using bi-directional inclusion sets equality

$\implies )$

$\mathbb Q(\pm \sqrt 3)\subseteq \mathbb Q(\pm \sqrt 3-3)$

Why?

$\Longleftarrow )$

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $3\in\mathbb{Q}$, $\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}-3)$ and $\sqrt{3}-3\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$. Now recall that $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Both polynomials are irreducible, by Eisenstein.

The number $-3+\alpha$ is a root of the latter polynomial. Therefore $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and both field extensions have degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.